# Apache mod_rewrite - How to hide $_GET vars from url

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, get

When I call the page

```
http://localhost/books-123-name.html?language_id=1
```

to appear in the browser the following link:

```
http://localhost/books-123-name.html
```

but will keep the value **language_id=1**

How can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Biggest question that seems to be appearing is why? Security? Friendly URLs? Kicks and giggles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to store information about requests other than GET parameters. One is using cookies, and you could store language_id in a cookie. A special case of using cookies would be using a session. You could also pass the language_id in a POST request, because POST parameters are invisible to the user. You might also use mod_rewrite to still use GET parameters, but make them prettier.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't.

The browser needs those values there in order to read them.

You could try reading them in, doing something with them and then redirecting to a page without the parameters.

Or use `POST`.

But more importantly, why?

Comment: >why? security reasons mostly or make it more similar to an desktop app (prettier) in some cases

Comment: If it is for security reasons then there is something very wrong with the OP's website/application. If it is for friendly URLs then the OP has asked the wrong question or at least asked it in a very poor way. We need more information from the OP before getting to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Like [jakenoble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625544/apache-mod-rewrite-how-to-hide-get-vars-from-url/3625589#3625589) said use `POST`.

Or Maybe you can use a different url pattern like

> `http://localhost/{human-readable-language}/books-123-name.html`

e.g. `http://localhost/en/books-123-name.html`

to

> `http://localhost/books-123-name.html?language_id={languade-id}`

e.g. `http://localhost/books-123-name.html?language_id=1`